# Passing Class Method to std::async in C++

Tags: c++, class

How can I pass class method to `std::async`?

Example:

```cpp
#include <future>
#include <iostream>

class ExampleClass { public: 
    void exampleMethod() {
        std::cout << "foo\n";
    }

    auto initializeExampleMethod() {
        return std::async(std::launch::async, &this->handler, &this);
    }
}
```

In Visual Studio Code (on Windows) it shows error `a pointer to a bound function may only be used to call the function`. How can I solve this easily?

Comment: The "similar question" also doesn't works.

Comment: "doesn't works" is not a problem description! Why not? What code did you write? What error did you get? [Edit] your question to show everything you've tried and the specific problems encountered.

Comment: Pls read the dupe carefully. It has the syntax `&Person::sum`, which in your case would be `&ExampleClass::exampleMethod`. `&this->handler` is not the right syntax for pointer-to-member. Also change `&this` to `this`.